# SharePoint Lists 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working on SharePoint 2010 and i have a two little queries, One is about how to connect two lists? and second query is how do i set item level permission?

I have a list called Employee_PIM where in it consists of Employee id, name, DOB, Address etc. There's one more list called Employee_Attendance where in it consists of En_No, Check in and Check Out Time and total duration of hours worked.

Now my question is how do i connect these two table in such a way where it shows En_No(Employee_Attendance List) is that particular Employee's Name(Employee_PIM List).......???

How can i relate these two table?

Second, If i set user permission to read and stop inheriting permission, that particular user can only see his/her records and cannot edit.

But i want user permission set in such a way, that the particular user can view and also edit his/her records but not other's.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lookup column and give reference of second list which ever column you want to show select it

Also, modify your view whatever fields you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Your Employee_Attendance list will lookup into Employee_PIM list. This will make them related. You can choose which column(s) from lookuped list (Employee_PIM) will be displayed in Employee_Attendance.

Your second question can be accomplished by list item event receiver that will be fired when item into Employee_Attendance list is added/updated. It can set permissions for added/updated item according to specified Employee. But your Employee_PIM needs to be extended by People or Group column as permissions can be set only form uses or group but not for your Employee_PIM list items.